Why is my mulberry cutting dying?
I planted these cuttings around April 25. By May 15, I got some beautiful new buds on some of the cuttings. Yet in the past 2 weeks, I've noticed them declining. Even my strongest bud started to go pale and wither away. I had them outside in partial shade growing in Pro-Mix (probably too wet promix in hindsight?). I've tried heating mats and humidity tents, which don't seem to do anything. Neither does misting the leaves. They're now pretty dried up, albeit still green.
What am I doing wrong? Is this guy done for?




If the cutting fails to develop roots, the resources within the stick will support leaves for a while, and then give out.
You can tent in plastic to reduce evaporation/transpiration (but that can also lead to mold if done too much) and you perhaps should have used rooting hormone on the stick bases (which you haven't said one way or the other if you did or did not.)
Some claim that you can make homebrew rooting hormone as "willow water" and water a cutting with it - might be worth a shot. Might also be too late for these particular cuttings.

It's got 2 coats of Clonex on the roots, spaced out by a couple weeks.

"spaced out by a couple weeks." implying that you pulled them up after a couple weeks to apply more? Not generally a good plan, IME - anything that's started developing would be lost, doing that.

Howso? I didn't see any root buds.

If some small, fine roots had started developing they could easily be ripped off without leaving much of a trace.

Ah, in that case I was careful to excavate them out instead of just yanking them up.

In the future, if I see buds should I nip them so they save their energy for roots?

You need some leaves. If you get more leaves than the roots can support you might want to reduce them, but eliminating all of them is not going to help your odds...for some things it's common to set out hardwood cuttings in the fall, so they can root over the winter and make leaves in spring. Then some get more complicatted with soil heating cables in the root zone so the top is dormant but the bottom is more active. I'm not sure what's commonly successful or required when rooting mulberries, specifically.

I took out (carefully, still leaving the dirt on) one of the bigger sticks and noticed some odd bulging near the base: almost like it's pregnant and has "tiger stripes" of green cambium. Does that sound like it's doing anything?
